# How to call xml (title) tags using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I have one xml file which main root starts with:

```
<design title="standard Cards 3.5 x 2" >
      <previews></previews>
      <previews1></previews1>
      <previews2></previews2>
   </design>
```

I want to read that xml files and get title tags and assign in option value.

I also got this `design` root tags by using this [w3school method](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_examples.asp) .i want to get `design` --> `title` and stored into my select box:

Here my code:

```
var selectHTML = "";
selectHTML += "<select name='something' id='media' onchange='select();'>";
for (i = 0; i < total.length; i = i + 1) {
    if (total[i] != '') {
        xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc($loc);
        var fruits = xmlDoc.documentElement.nodeName;
        if (fruits) {
            alert(fruits);
            var name = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("design")
            alert(name);
        }
        selectHTML += "<option value='" + total[i] + "'>" + name + "</option>";
    }
}
selectHTML += "</select>";
```

Here `xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc($loc);` is calling method of xml files.I refer this from [w3school tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodes_access.asp)

I just alerting **`name`**  it resulting undefined. How to solve this?

I want to place **`name`** value into my select box option value. How to read xml files using javascript and place into option value?

Comment: (for starters - have a look here and the resources it points to http://www.w3fools.com/).  Secondly your javascript doesn't seem to match your xml?  you are looking for  a node code fruits1 but your xml has 'design' with the title.  Also this seems to be a duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599218/having-trouble-input-html-list-option-from-xml-file

Comment: oops..sorry..@TygerKrash..I updated my answer..ya your correct my xml can`t match this var name = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("design") line..it results to be [object HTMLCollection]..how to call this attribute?

Comment: Since you are using jquery anyway, it may become easier with this -  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Comment: Hi @techfoobar..Thank you for response my question..I want it in javascript becz entire file i working in javascript.Hope i have one query when i used in jquery means it will affect my javascript ?Can you advise me..

Comment: Oh.. i thought i saw the jquery tag in the question earlier. Maybe i thought it wrong! :-)

Comment: Oh @techfoobar, Thanks you for revise my question.when i used jquery means i want to place this title value into  select option? is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try by

```
var name = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("design");
var value = name[0].getAttribute('title')
alert(value);
```

---

also in the w3school example, the `loadXMLDoc` is a function which is defined manually. It uses `XMLHttpRequest()` and `ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")` According to your browser type. So if you dint include `loadXMLDoc` definition, then there will be errors.

Comment: @user2711066 : sorry i dint get you? is it working for you now?

Comment: your code worked perfectly...I want to place it in my option value..i will also worked and show correct value.

Comment: @user2711066 : yes i just pointed out how to pick up the attribute value `title` from the `nodelist` you got which your code was not doing.

Comment: @mithunsatheesh..this code will more helpful for me...my select box will show correctly..Thank you for make me happy..and i need to clarify some thing.I want to read xml file using javascript do you know any kind of tutorial..

Comment: @user2711066 : you can check [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204165/using-javascript-to-parse-an-xml-file) which has the same code you are using explained. Also reading [Parsing_and_serializing_XML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Parsing_and_serializing_XML) and [how-to-parse-a-XMl-file-with-a-jquery](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/414848/how-to-parse-a-XMl-file-with-a-jquery)  will give more clarity.

Comment: Hi @mithunsatheesh...my xml file function in javascript can`t load in chrome..How to solve it can you know it?

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a punt at this.

- Assuming that your $loc  is just the filename...

from what I can tell loadXMLDoc()  will load an xml document from the same context as the document that executes it (in this case the html page)

If the page executing that JavaScript is in a different directory to the XMl file it will fail to load.